# Why did Jesus need to suffer?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, suffering

What is the purpose of Jesus suffering? If Jesus represents God, why does God need to suffer?

It doesn't make sense to me that it is for the sake of forgiving us, because I hope God forgives us regardless, and doesn't need sacrifices to do it.

I do connect to the implication of God suffering with us, and that we are not alone in suffering, but still don't understand, why does God need to suffer.

Comment: Related to, but different from [Why did Jesus have to die?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16485/6071)

Comment: I don't think it is the same question. My question is : What is the purpose of Jesus/ God suffering. I cannot believe that it is in order to forgive sins . Nor do I understand how this suffering shows love for us., If god is love god does't need to make an horrible sacrifice in order to forgive and love. There must be another reason that god suffered then, and maybe suffer now with us.

Comment: I suggest asking a few new questions: why did Jesus need to suffer to forgive sins? and why does Jesus show love by suffering?